# VBA code to run as a different network user

Tags: vba, excel, file-permissions, directory

Is it possible for me to run VBA code as a different user, thereby preventing the user from directly renaming \ deleting certain files and folders, but allowing the program to run as a different user that is allowed to rename \ delete certain files and folders.

Comment: When execute Excel execute it as another user, the only way.

Comment: you could write a .NET exe program and run that under a different identity, then export a COM interface so VBA can call it, the .NET program would have to register a class with the Running Object Table.

Comment: VBA runs in-process. The user that owns the EXCEL.EXE process owns the credentials the VBA code is running with.

Comment: why all the vote downs.  It's a valid question, and we have some comments as possible answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a batch file that has this code in it.
I have my authorized excel users double click on this batch file.
I give them the password.
The account is a service account, so it doesn't have any log in priviledges.

It works!
This way, I remove my user base from directly having access to certain files and folders.  They have to let the macros to the file manipulation....

My Batch File:

```
runas /user:ALLIEDFIT\kmistry /savecred "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Excel.exe \"S:\Allied MTRS\Allied MTRS Auto\Awaji_Auto\_Prod_Push.xlsm\""
```

Comment: i don't appreciate all the vote downs.  it is a valid question, and I posted a valid answer!

Comment: Yeah it's odd, the VBA community here constantly votes questions down with little to no explanation.